# How to print unicode emoticons in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, unicode, emoticons

I'm creating a chat room using Javascript/jQuery, PHP and Websockets. I want to support Unicode emoticons. I have a DIV with emoticons and, when user click in one of them, the emoticon is inserted in an input box. Simple.

User press "enter" and the text is sent to PHP. But PHP can't understand the emoticon (shows "??"), so I did a function in Javascript to convert to \uXXXX format (4-bytes) before submit to PHP.

Example:

1) User submits "testtest"

2) Javascript converts to "test\uD83D\uDE00test" (function below) - If I go to Chrome console and type "test\uD83D\uDE00test" it shows "testtest" correctly, so, the converted string is correct.

3) Submit the string to PHP: "test\uD83D\uDE00test"

4) PHP sends to Websocket that will only append the string into a DIV, something like `$('#chat').append(d)`, where "d" (received from socket.io object) contains "test\uD83D\uDE00test".

But it shows the string "test\uD83D\uDE00test"... I want to show the emoticon.

Where is my error?

---

Function to convert emoticons to \u format: scan all chars and modify only the non-ascii ones.

```
function ChatUCode(t) {
 S='';
 for (a=0;a<t.length;a++) {
  if (t.charCodeAt(a)>255) {
   S+='\\u'+('0000'+t.charCodeAt(a).toString(16)).substr(-4,4).toUpperCase();
  } else {
   S+=t.charAt(a);
  }
 }
 return S;
}
```

Comment: Both jquery `$(...).append('test\uD83D\uDE00test')` and vanilla js `[...].innerHTML += 'test\uD83D\uDE00test')` seem to work appropriately.  This seems to me to be a translation across the network.  That is, whatever is coming from the websocket thinks the string needs the literal `\` and `u` and such.  You may want to consider something like json-encoding and decoding, or some other method of encoding/decoding to prevent this issue (among other random issues from network translations)

Comment: Yeah @cegfault, I agree, but I did several tests about this too... the websocket is returning correctly if I only print the string using console.log(). But you gave me a good idea, process the string using Json functions. I'll try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, thanks to @cegfault idea.

Sending the string to `JSON.parse` function, it will show the emoticons correctly. But I had to escape the string to JSON format.

```
$('#chat').append(JSON.parse('"'+d+'"'));
```

Another way, not so secure, is the same idea but using `eval()` function, between quotes too.